# how to insert json variable to httpClient get url parametres in ionic 5

Tags: json, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

i'm using ionic 5 and i want get ip from client user and put it in url get
i'm using this for get the ip

```
this.ipclient = this.httpClient.get("https://api.ipify.org/?format=json");
this.ipclient
.subscribe(ipclient => {
console.log('my ip is: ', ipclient);
});
```

and i want put result in another place

```
this.offs = this.httpClient.get("https://example.com/?affiliateid=1507&ip=(i want put ip here)&device=android");
this.offs
.subscribe(offs => {
console.log('my result: ', offs);
});
```

i need help for that if that's possible thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to chain them, you can use switchMap as below

```
    this.httpClient.get("https://api.ipify.org/?format=json")
    .pipe(
      switchMap((ipclient: string) => this.httpClient.get(`https://example.com/?affiliateid=1507&ip=${ipclient}&device=android`))
    )
    .subscribe(offs => {
        console.log('my result: ', offs);
    })
```

Comment: Thank you i think will work with switchmap, thanks i'm find the solution it work now for me with HttpParams

Comment: @abdelghanisougrati glad to hear that, so please mark it as correct answer, so other devs with same issue will find it useful